# Destroy/Stop MediaPlayer when switching fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I have a tablet view with a side pannel and the main fragment to the right. Issue is I have a MediaPlayer that continues playing even when someone switches to another fragment, this means when the user goes back onto the fragment, it cause crashes with the pause button. How would I make it so once a user press another fragment, it stop/destroys the MediaPlayer?

```
public class Fragment_7 extends Fragment {

private MediaPlayer mp;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_7, null);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);





    GridView gridView = (GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound01);
                    mp.start();

                    // This will make  sound
                    break;
                case 1:
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound02);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 2:

                        stopPlaying();
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound03);
                        mp.start();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound04);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    stopPlaying();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound05);
                    mp.start();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store"));
                    startActivity(i);

                    break;
            }
        }
    });
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.fab);

            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.pause();
                        mp.seekTo(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }}}
```

Comment: Override onStop in your Fragment and stop the MediaPlayer there